# Multiple database users for ASP.Net MVC project SQL Server Auditing, or roll our own?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, audit

We currently have a SQL Server 2008 instance set up for our ASP.Net MVC application, and the SQL Server instance uses built-in auditing (I believe CDC?)

We also have our ASP.Net application set up to use **one** connection string specified in web.config for the entire application, no matter who is logged in (of about ~50 users)

The problem: **We want to be able to include among the audit information the username of the user who made the particular change in question.**

It looks like we can only do that in one of two ways:

1. **Change our application setup so that every single user gets their own database login.** This would require us to use dynamic connection strings (perhaps not too terrible), but moreover it would be a pain in the ass to add a new user to the system and the admins could no longer do it automagically via the application's interface (I think).
2. **Use another solution from within the ASP.Net app itself**. This would allow us to trivially add any bit of information in the application we wish, but would involve scrapping the entire builtin solution and essentially starting from scratch with a significant effort.

Someone must have run into this problem before with auditing - is #1 feasible? Or is #2 the only way we can go here?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose using Windows logins are out of the question?

Answer (score 1):

Option #1 is pain for the admins, a little complicated code for "dynamic" connection strings, and calling sp_addlogin to create users. But the worst is that separate DB login for every user also allows them to query DB directly (if they know instance & database names, which could leak to them in any way and "see" DB server through the network). Direct access to the DB is something that may crash every application. Don't do it, unless you're very sure that DB server is not directly reachable to the users.

About #2. How about adding column "LastModifiedLogin" to every table, where you put login of logged in user during every insert/update? This shouldn't crash CDC and you got what you want. However auditing delete is little problematic, because you issue statement and have no longer row where you could place the login. You may organize seperate "DeleteAudit" table where you put name of table, row identifier and user login on every delete, but that's only rough idea.

If you use NHibernate for data access, I would advise you to consider switching CDC to NHibernate Envers, which is very neat solution.